# Split a column and append to existing values in other columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing some hard challenge in data cleaning using pandas. I need to work on the ZIP, State and City columns in the dataframe (as attached).

This is the glimpse of the data:

```
    City         State        ZIP   
0   PEARLAND       TX        77584
1   HOT SPRINGS    AR        7191
2   PALMDALE       CA        93551
3   JONESBOROY     AR        72401
4   WATSONVILLE    CA        95076
5   SACRAMENTO     UCA       95823      
6   AGOURAT       HILLS      CA 91301
7   JSAN          DIEGO      CA 92114
8   NEW           PORT       RICHEY FL 34655
9   BURBANK        CA        91501
```

Challenge I am facing: 
The Zip column should contain only the Zip number, The state column should have only 2 digit state code, and city should have valid city name.

For example:

```
    City          State        ZIP
6   AGOURAT       HILLS      CA 91301
7   JSAN          DIEGO      CA 92114
8   NEW           PORT       RICHEY FL 34655
```

should be -

```
    City               State        ZIP
6   AGOURAT HILLS      CA         91301
7   JSAN DIEGO         CA         92114
8   NEW PORT RICHEY    FL         34655
```

So can anyone help me how can I achieve this using Pandas dataframe?

Comment: What's the raw input?  It seems like you may have made a mistake in the initial parsing and it would be good to go another step further back.  Checkout this address parsing library: https://github.com/datamade/usaddress

Comment: I am reading a csv file with 11 columns as input. RecID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, City, State, ZIP, POBox, SSN, DOB. And then I am supposed to clean this data where I am facing problem with the above mentioned 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to read the data once again using regex. If not, redo.

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(' '.join, axis = 1)
df[['City', 'State', 'Zip']] = df['combined'].str.extract('([A-Z ]+)\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+(\d+)', expand = True)
df.drop('combined', axis = 1, inplace = True)



    City            State   ZIP
0   PEARLAND        TX  77584
1   HOT SPRINGS     AR  7191
2   PALMDALE        CA  93551
3   JONESBOROY      AR  72401
4   WATSONVILLE     CA  95076
5   NaN             NaN NaN
6   AGOURAT HILLS   CA  91301
7   JSAN DIEGO      CA  92114
8   NEW PORT RICHEY FL  34655
9   BURBANK         CA  91501
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. But there are few rows with State names rather than 2 character codes (for e.g., Texas instead of TX). I think I would need to do something else for such rows.

Comment: Yeah it's messy and there is no one right solution. May be replace all state names with 2 character codes using df.replace({'TEXAS' : 'TX'}) and then try my solution